# PC boots to black page, asks which configuration you want (xp / safe mode) etc. loops

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot

After you pick which configuration you want to use it loops again and again, then sometimes it loads up windows page for 5-10 mins then shuts down and starts all over again.

I did notice warm air coming out of power supply fan and yes its working, once I get to the windows page there is no time to run `AVG` or any other antivirus program before it shuts down again then it starts looping to the black page again.

I have tried:

- safe mode
- latest configuration that worked
- XP windows, etc

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made any changes to, perhaps the registry? This is surely not a hardware problem. Perhaps a virus, but if you can't find a way to launch one you may have to go to a pro.

Comment: Your question is awful to understand!

Comment: Get a Linux Live Cd (http://www.livecdlist.com/operating-system/linux), like gparted, systemrescue or parted magic (any release would work). Burn it to cd/usb, and boot your computer to it. Mount the hd, and backup all your data, then re-install windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the OS loads up for a few minutes, it suggests OS is ok, fault is with hardware. First, check event viewer for any clues and ensure that BSOD message is configured to display.

However, due to OS starting it suggests hardware or driver issue. Remove all unneeded hardware and USB drives and no dvd/cd and only 1 hard drive. Try again.

If this fixes it then slowly add hardware back bit bit until you find the fault?

Answer (score 0):

Immediately when your computer starts booting, tap F8 repeatedly.  You will be presented with the Advanced Boot Options menu.  Press the down arrow key until "Disable automatic restart on system failure" is selected, then press ENTER.  Then do the above again, but select "Repair your computer."  See if this works for you.